# Bone broth has green tint; is this normal?

Tags: food-safety, broth

Is it normal for bone broth to have a green tint? I skimmed a bit off and it looked like sautéed spinach. The broth itself had a slight green tint. I'm not sure whether that's okay or a sign of something being amiss. Could it be caused by the bone marrow, fats, etc?

Comment: What type of bones? How was the meat to which the bones originally belonged cooked?

Comment: And did you add anything at all apart from bones and water?

Comment: Eeeuw!  That would worry me too

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add more details: what other ingredients you used, what kind of pot, meat, method, etc.